# 16.04.2 LTS. Create an ISO of entire installation, which can be installed elsewhere

Tags: 16.04, apache2, iso, ruby-on-rails

I have an ubuntu server acting as a web server. It runs a Ruby on Rails application using Passenger + Apache.

I'd like to create an ISO of the installation, including everything needed to create copies of the ubuntu server. Specifically, my colleague plans to virtualize my ubuntu installation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unless you insist on creating an .iso, it is probably easiest to achieve your goal of cloning your machine to a virtual one by  using Clonezilla.

Comment: My colleague insists. Thank you, I've been reading the documentation.

Comment: You could use remastersys, but that is a bit different than what you want :-)